# How to implement websocket/sse with OpenId on Quarkus?

Tags: java, security, openid-connect, quarkus, undertow

## Hi everyone

,

I'm using **Quarkus 1.2.0 Final**, and I want to implement a **websocket and sse events with security**.


I'm using the **oidc extension** of quarkus which autenticate my users with the Authorization header.
I don't know how to implement security on my websocket or sse because I can't pass the token in the url with access_token=eyerggtrgtg... parameter to authenticate and it doesn't work with Cookie too.

Thank you,

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get to solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes. I did a an Entity class which store an UUID associated with creation date and username of the person. The user make an Http request which create a ticket an return it to the user. Then the user try to connect on the websocket endpoint with the ticket as a url parameter. In my @OnOpen I verify the ticket, the username associated and if it's not expired (I took 5 min). And I store the session In a concurrentHashmap with in the session.getUserAttribute().add / or put I put the username to know that this session is this user

Comment: I forgot, I had a property isUsed on the ticket in the databse. Like this it's a one time code.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks. But it is your custom support. This is like sending JWT token in onConnect/onOpen and validating that. I was more looking for inherent support in Quarkus. Jetty Keycloak adapter provides this functionality of reading token from query param itself, so no extra validation required.

Comment: Passing the access token in the url throw a 414 URI too long, but If you increase that, I think you can make a Filter that take the parameter and put it in the header with the routingContext (https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json) take a look a the LoggingFilter exemple

Comment: You can follow this issue to have the latest update about that : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7414

Comment: Yes, I was considering that. But my question on this is how quarkus decide the order of filter. I have read about pre-match, postmatch and priority. But here, it is not clear that whether my filter will be before oidc or after. I think it would be before oidc but how quarkus is deciding that? What if I want to put a filter after oidc but before my rest API.

Comment: That's a good question, I think you can post an issue on their Github to help others whom want to do the same.